# Format simple_form collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use [`grouped_collection_select`](http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/25/grouped-select-helper-methods-in-rails/) but my data act differently.

I have for exemple `Post` that have_many `comments`. I can do `Post.find(:id).comments` but can't do `Comment.find(:id).posts`. `Comment` belongs to an `author` and `author` belongs to `post`.

I would like to add to my form a select filtered by comment author :

```
= grouped_collection_select(:post, :id, @posts, :comments, :title, :id, :author)
```

I know it's wrong but how can I invert it? For the moment it return me something like

```
<select name="posts[:id]">
  <optgroup label="Post 1 title">
    <option value="4536">Soica</option>
    <option value="56775">Bob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Post 2 title">
    <option value="7897" selected="selected">Sandy</option>
    <option value="266">Sarah</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is it possible to trick it and filter it by comments author ? Maybe `grouped_collection_select` is not the best solution?

Comment: Why doesn't comment belongs_to post as well?

Comment: @bo-oz because you have comment->author->Post // post -> comments

Comment: comment can still have a belongs_to post as well... max has a nice explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably simplefy your relations and app considerably by declaring the relations as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :post
end
```

[image: Database sketch]

Note that in a `belongs_to` relation you need to use the singular form. So to go from comments to posts you would always use:

```
Comment.find(6).post
```

Not `.posts`. Its pretty unlikely that you want a many to many model where a comment may belong to many posts.

Writing a query on `authors` based on comments is a bit tricky but defiantly doable.

```
@authors = Author.includes(:comments)
                 .where(comments: { post_id: 7 })
                 .order(:name) # or however you want to sort it.
```

And you would create the input like so:

```
grouped_collection_select(
  :post, 
  :id, 
  @authors, 
  :comments, 
  :name, 
  :id, 
  :name
)
```

Comment: Thanks @max. Gonna try to implement it.

Comment: Edited slight typo should be `.where(comments: { post_id: 7 })` not `comment`.